# Securing Mongodb for use by a windows service

Tags: mongodb, authentication, passwords, windows-server-2008

I have a windows service that runs as a particular domain user. This service requires access to MongoDB. Can I configure mongo to accept this domain user or is the only way to use a mongo username and password in some config somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External authentication is supported for MongoDB 2.4 Server (Enterprise edition only) running on Linux. If your database is running on Linux and you are using the .Net or Java driver to connect to it, you could set up using Kerberos as the external authentication provider. More information can be found at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/ or : http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-java-driver/